# Procedure with 2 results in same output

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

Is there anyway to return a output like this?

My procedure is empty but is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
    @in_USERID

AS
BEGIN

        SELECT FROM UsersGroups ug, Accounts ac, GroupsRooms gr, Posts po WHERE
        ug.USER_ID  =   @in_USERID 
        OR -- and my question is here. How can I read the other users that are in the same group only knowing the id of 1 user.

END
```

Here my structure:

[image: Question Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected result, I write the query below:

it will result the *SELECT ALL USERS WHO ARE IN THE SAME GROUP OF USERID ENTERED + ALL GROUPS*.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
    @in_USERID INT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT UG.GR_ID, GR.POST_ID, PO.POST_NAME, UG.[USER_ID], AC.[NAME]
    FROM UsersGroups UG
    JOIN Accounts AC ON AC.[USER_ID] = UG.[USER_ID]
    JOIN GroupsRooms GR ON GR.GR_ID = UG.GR_ID
    JOIN Posts PO ON PO.POST_ID = GR.POST_ID
    WHERE UG.[USER_ID] = @in_USERID

    UNION

    SELECT UG.GR_ID, GR.POST_ID, PO.POST_NAME, UG.[USER_ID], AC.[NAME]
    FROM UsersGroups UG
    JOIN Accounts AC ON AC.[USER_ID] = UG.[USER_ID]
    JOIN GroupsRooms GR ON GR.GR_ID = UG.GR_ID
    JOIN Posts PO ON PO.POST_ID = GR.POST_ID
    JOIN UsersGroups SUG ON SUG.GR_ID = UG.GR_ID
    WHERE UG.[USER_ID] != @in_USERID AND SUG.[USER_ID] = @in_USERID;

END
```

Please find the <kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://rextester.com/YRXDE40385)</kbd>

Comment: I got an error using your procedure  [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'WHERE'.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. But why there is 2 same "SELECT" ? It works but return only 1 value (The value of the userID entered). This should return the other users too. Maybe because the @in_USERID is the same?

Comment: If I'm not wrong with != the query will select all values even when the user is not in the group. I mean if my @in_USERID = 5 .. SHOUld return only the users that are in GR_Id = 100

Comment: Yes, check this expected result. In this image you can understand better: http://i.imgur.com/Y8aL1Qv.png  (I'm using 3 as @in_USERID)

Comment: perhaps you've misunderstood. I'm asking for output all users that are in the same group of the in_USERID (including in_USERID) + all groups of the in_USERID

Comment: @DexSebas: Yes, Really I misunderstood your requirement. Now updated with the working demo. Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TEST @in_USERID
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM UsersGroups
    WHERE UsersGroups.Id IN (SELECT UsersGroups.ID FROM UsersGroups ug WHERE ug.USER_ID  =   @in_USERID )
END
```

Comment: Hello, I tested that but return all values from table UsersGroups